# Add conditions on my ajax request (if and else)

Tags: javascript, ajax

How can add conditions on my ajax request? 
When I add the code on below is active just for only one.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: urlPost,
  success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
      createPostItem(value.name, value.image, value.size);
      if (value.size == 'post') {
        $('#img-size').addClass("img-post")
      } else {
        $('#img-size').addClass("img-story")
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! This looks like an interesting question, but please provide some additional details so that we can help you. For example, what do you mean by conditions, and what is the final result you are looking for? Additionally, what do you mean that it is active for only one? Please edit your question so that we can better understand what you need.

Comment: hi, ty !! My problem is resolve, i would like resize my img with a new var (and now and i try add absolute div with another div in relative ("2nd div") but the 2nd div is not a parent (the divs are a the same level)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are manipulating the same element (with id *img-size*) for each data point received from the server. The result is that the element is affected by all data points, which may not be what you desire. I imagine that you may want to manipulate a different element for each data point, but this is not clear from the question.

**UPDATE** (after clarification):

I would suggest modifying the function **createPostItem**:

```js
var urlPost = "assets/js/imgStock.json"
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: urlPost,
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            createPostItem(value.name, value.image, value.madeFor, value.size);
        });
    }
});

function createPostItem(name, image, madeFor, size) {
    var width, height;

    if (size == 'story') {
        height = '472px';
        width = '270px';
    }
    else {
        height = '270px';
        width = '270px';
    }

    var html = '<div class="imgStock w-full border-4 my-auto border-blue-500 lg:mx-2 mt-4 mx-auto">' +
        '<div class="flex post text-gray-200 animate__animated animate__fadeIn">' +
        '<div class="img-size mx-auto relative transition duration-300 ease-in transform hover:-translate-y-2" style="width: ' + width + '; height: ' + height + ';">' +
        '<img class="rounded shadow-2xl" src="' + image + '" alt="' + name + '"' +
        '<div class="btn-i absolute ">' +
        '<div class="btn-i absolute text-center pt-2 animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft pl-2">' + name + '</div>' +
        '<span class="flex absolute font-semibold tracking-wide justify-center absolute-pill px-1 text-xxs bg-yellow-400 text-gray-900 rounded-full text-xs">' + madeFor + '</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';

    $(".images-array").append(html);
}
```

Comment: Sorry it's my first post on stackoverflow and i'm very bad in english, yep I want to manipulate a different element for each data point, thanks u a lot to read me

Comment: If the ids of the elements to be manipulated correspond in some way to the data of the data point, you can do something like this (not actual solution, just an example):
`$('#' + value.image).addClass("img-post")`

Comment: I have the same id on my ajax request "#img-size" i would like resize the image when it have a different value (post / story). I think I can't change id for each ?

Comment: Do you have multiple images with the same id? Could you, please, share more information about the HTML elements you are trying to manipulate?

Comment: i add the answer

Answer (score 0):

(I use a Tailwind css)

My ajax request:

```
var urlPost = "assets/js/imgStock.json"
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: urlPost,
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        createPostItem(value.name, value.image, value.madeFor, value.size);
        if(value.size == 'story'){
            $('.img-size').css("height", "472")
            $('.img-size').css("height", "270")

        } else {
            $('.img-size').css("height", "270px")

            $('.img-size').css("width", "270px")

        }
        // $('#'+value.size).addClass("img-post")
    });
}
```

});

function to create html:

```
function createPostItem(name,image, madeFor, size) {
var html = '<div class="imgStock w-full border-4 my-auto border-blue-500 lg:mx-2 mt-4 mx-auto">' +
    '<div class="flex post text-gray-200 animate__animated animate__fadeIn">' +
    '<div class="img-size mx-auto relative transition duration-300 ease-in transform hover:-translate-y-2">' +
    '<img class="rounded shadow-2xl" src="' + image + '" alt="' + name + '"' +
    '<div class="btn-i absolute ">' +
    '<div class="btn-i absolute text-center pt-2 animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft pl-2">' + name + '</div>' +
    '<span class="flex absolute font-semibold tracking-wide justify-center absolute-pill px-1 text-xxs bg-yellow-400 text-gray-900 rounded-full text-xs">' + madeFor + '</span>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

$(".images-array").append(html);
```

}

Doc Json:
 `[
  {
    "name": "Calendrier Sofiane Boufal",
    "image": "img/Boufal_Story.jpg",
    "size": "story",
    "madeFor": "Asala Finances"
  },
  {
    "name": "Cover fictive rap",
    "image": "img/Roshi_Cover.jpg",
    "size": "post",
    "madeFor": "Captain Roshi"
  },
  {
    "name": "Calendrier Jean-Pierre Nsame",
    "image": "img/mars_nsame.jpg",
    "size":  "story",
    "madeFor": "Asala Finances"
  },
  {
    "name": "Anniveraire Houboulang Mendes",
    "image": "img/Mendes-Birthday.jpg",
    "size":  "story",
    "madeFor": "Asala Finances"
  }
]`

i edit my conditions (if, else) for add the css on the class, i had the same id for multiples images you were right but i still does not work /:

result (:my value.size == "story" are the biggests images (name: calendrier southampton, calendrier young boys, and happy birthday)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ7oA.jpg)